# Is there any kind of unsecured stock loan?

Tags: stocks, loans, india

I am interested to buy some shares in the future. Can anybody tell me is there any kind of stock loan which doesn't need collateral?

Comment: The only loan that does not require any collateral is called a Personal Loan that is available from any bank.

Comment: @Dheer you should write it as an answer.

Comment: OP - what's your location? Although I doubt that there are any investment-funding loans left after the crashes of 1999 and 2008, I know of some countries that used to have such things.

Comment: consider a call option in the future.

Comment: @Himanshu Think twice before doing that, it's risky.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but how is it a stock loan if there's no collateral? If I am a money lender, and you offer no collateral, I have no assurance you'll buy what you plan to. This question seems to be "can I get an unsecured loan?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buy an option, they cost less and let you buy shares in the future at the price you see now.

only if you plan to buy more than 100 shares of the stock at that future date though.

better learn how to use options strategically first, which I won't go into. but this is indeed their purpose.

Comment: how is it answering the question?

Comment: its a better decision than getting a stock loan. he wants to buy stock in the future because he doesn't have money now. scrounge up less money and buy an option that expires at the future time that you expect to have money.

Comment: then it should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: I never saw that in the FAQ, but I only skimmed it. where is that rule?

Comment: Here: http://money.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion, see the portion that says *Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed*.

Comment: @littleadv Yeah but his answer is good, so it should stay.

Answer (score 4):

In the U.S. it is typical that a stock brokerage account can be set up to buy stock with up to half the cost being borrowed from the broker.  This is called a margin account.  The stock purchased must remain in the account until sold (or the loan is paid off), as it serves as built-in collateral for the loan.  If the market price for the stock goes down too much, you will be required to add money, or the stock will be sold to cover the loan. See [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9481/other-than-being-able-to-borrow-to-invest-how-is-a-margin-trading-account-diffe) for some more information.